# Ng Click Doesn't work in Nav Bar

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a simple ng-click in the nav bar and it doesn't work. I've placed the html template inside of a directive but the alert does not appear. There are no other issues in my console. I'm stumped as to why this doesn't work.

```
<signed-in-header></signed-in-header>
```

My directive as a whole.

```
angular.module('CoolSite.user')

.directive('signedInHeader', signedInHeader)

function signedInHeader() {
  return {
    template: template,
    link: link,
    scope: { }
  }

  function link(scope, elem, attrs) {
    scope.alert = function() {console.log("ALERTED")}
  }

  function template() {
    return [
      '<ion-nav-bar class="bar-light" align-title="center">',
        '<ion-nav-buttons side="left">',
          '<img ng-click="alert(123)" height="30" src="/img/logo-full.png">',
        '</ion-nav-buttons>',

        '<ion-nav-buttons side="right">',
          '<div ui-sref="tab.cart">',
            '<i class="icon ion-ios-cart-outline"></i>',
            '<div id="cartCount" class="assertive">1</div>',
          '</div>',
        '</ion-nav-buttons>',
      '</ion-nav-bar>'
    ].join("");
  }
}
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/8CHdeRmDtG52PgvAbucG?p=preview).

Comment: Could you setup an example of this guy?  Jbin or something?

Comment: Ergh, I was hoping to not have to but I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Trying to set something up myself ;)  We'll see who gets it first

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/8CHdeRmDtG52PgvAbucG?p=preview

Comment: are you getting any console errors?

Comment: He says in his OP he isn't. I've just mocked this up in plain Angular and it works fine. See [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXYWGP)

Comment: Derp...wow sorry bout that.

Comment: it's a css rule from ionics css. answered below (thats why its working for you @DanPantry

Comment: The codepen has that CSS rule :)

Comment: Shouldn't the return be at the end?  I've been out of this stuff for a while...sorry if that's a newb question

Comment: huh..why...i just setup the same as the OP with ionic and saw it didn't work, removing this rule made it working. thats weird.

Comment: @Collin functions get hoisted. I've added that to the codepen, it works fine.

Comment: @DanPantry Okay true, the css rule is not the issue. but you setup together with ionic doesn't work.

Comment: There must be a discrepancy there, then. I do not use ionic so I am unable to assist further

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to add the `button` class to your image.  You can add `button-clear` so that the button border is not added.

```
<img class="button button-clear" ng-click="alert(123)" src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/hawcons/32/700015-icon-27-one-finger-click-32.png" />
```

## [Working Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/qVoChoC78Q9VC2HVZCcB?p=preview)

To clarify, everyone was correct on some level:

- icycool was right in that the actual issue is the z-index.  The ionic button class adds `z-index: 1`.
- Krytic points out that without the ionic css linked it will work (because the elements then just default to relative position and the button isn't obscured).
- aorfevre's suggestion to use a link worked not because it was an anchor tag, but because the link had the button class applied.

Comment: Thanks for solving the mystery!

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't specify a directive using id?

**Angular doc says:**

> The restrict option is typically set to: 
>   'A' - only matches attribute name 
>   'E' - only matches element name 
>   'C' - only matches class name

Maybe you can try adding it as an attribute?

```
<ion-nav-bar signed-in-header id="signedInHeader" class="bar-light" align-title="center">
```

Comment: You can't specify a directive via id, no. It only works via element, class or attribute (or comment). This is the issue with OP's code.

Comment: Wrong. There's a misunderstanding with my question. I've updated it.

Comment: People are upvoting because at time of posting, this was the correct answer *and* the code in the OP's question was radically different. Check the edit history. If you rewrite half of your question it's not a misunderstanding.

Comment: Wrong, see my response and updated example. It is perfectly working with id

Answer (score 1):

I have slightly updated your case with a templateUrl which is, in my opinion, much more readable.

http://plnkr.co/edit/8CHdeRmDtG52PgvAbucG?p=preview
Template here :

```
<ion-nav-bar id="signedInHeader" class="bar-light" align-title="center">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
      <a class="button button-icon button-clear " ng-click="test()">CLICK
    </a>
    </ion-nav-buttons>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

I have created a test function that is added to your directive link.

```
scope.test= function(){
  alert("TEST");
}
```

Comment: This is a workaround, not the answer, since you're using a `a` tag, instead of `img`

Comment: Sorry. It needs to be an img element.

Comment: your plnukr shows a div element, not an img...  unaccurate questions provides unaccurate answsers...

Comment: if there is a plunkr, shall we verify all code from plunkr this is equal to question ?

Comment: I'm not saying the plunkr with incorrect code isn't a farce but saying "inaccurate questions provide inaccurate answers" is pretty silly when th question itself does actually have an image element

Comment: I do not believe it matters whether it's a div or img. But if it's an anchor tag I can't use it I even tested it with wrapping an anchor tag around the image, and that doesn't work. This is a moot point.

Answer (score 0):

What you have to remember is that `ng-click` will look for a function bound to the current `$scope`, so if you do

```
ng-click="alert(123)"
```

it is looking for a function `$scope.alert` and will not find it.  It does not look in the `window` object to find it.

Answer (score 0):

Ionics CSS comes with this rule:

```
img {
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
}
```

Removing this from ionic.css or setting it to `auto` should solve this.

### Update:

this doesn't solve the issue for the OP. 
But using his plunkr, removing the `ionic.css` from the document fixes the issue. Just as a hint, the answer is somewhere out there ;)

Comment: Still a no-go. Sorry :(

Comment: which version of ionic are you using?

Comment: mhhh that's strange. even in your plunkr, removing the ionic.css at the top will fix the issue. has something to do with the ionic directive wrapping your clickable element. theres something like this described in my answer, or disabled pointer events or sth. similar happening with your element because of the css.

Comment: Great debugging! This should help in finding the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Some how the generated ionic code has it's title blocking its own button.

```
<ion-nav-bar id="signedInHeader" class="bar-light nav-bar-container" align-title="center" nav-bar-transition="ios">
    <ion-nav-buttons side="left" class="hide"></ion-nav-buttons>
    <ion-nav-buttons side="right" class="hide"></ion-nav-buttons>
    <div class="nav-bar-block" nav-bar="cached">
        ...
    </div>
    <div class="nav-bar-block" nav-bar="active">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-light bar bar-header disable-user-behavior" align-title="center">
            <div class="buttons buttons-left header-item">
                <span class="left-buttons">
                    <div ng-click="alert(123)">click me</div>
                </span>
            </div>
            <div class="title title-center header-item"></div> <!-- this line -->
            <div class="buttons buttons-right header-item">
                <span class="right-buttons">
                    <div>
                        <i class="icon ion-ios-cart-outline"></i>
                        <div id="cartCount" class="assertive">1</div>
                    </div>
                </span>
            </div>
        </ion-header-bar>
    </div>
</ion-nav-bar>
```

The title is having a css in ionic.css

```
.bar .title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  ...
}
```

In CSS rules `position:absolute` items will be placed on top of normal flow items.

There might be a way in ionic coding style that fixes this issue but I can't find it.

So I fixed it by raising the buttons and make it covers the title again

```
.bar .buttons-left {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Note that after this fix the left buttons will cover the title if title text is long enough to go under it, or the title text is aligned left.